# Image gets uploaded even when the ok button is not clicked

Tags: android, picasso

My blogging app is supposed to upload images and its description below the images. I am using picasso crop tool to crop images.

**The problem** : i click the image button to upload an image and then choose the image from the gallery, after choosing and cropping the image i change my mind and decide not to upload the image and simply press the back button. Nothing shows up in the image button as well. I simply type the description and post the blog. When the blogging page opens up the image is seen uploaded with the description even after pressing the back button without uploading the image to the image button whereas i wanted to display only the description. Why is this happening? Do i have to write some special conditional code to avoid such bug?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**Note: It happens only when i resize the image and press the back button without uploading it. If i dont do any resize and click the back button after selecting the image the problem doesnt arise.**

Code:

```
 private ImageButton selectimage;
selectimage= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
selectimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });



public void startposting(){
 StorageReference filepath=mstorage.child("Place_Image").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("description").setValue(desc);
                    newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());


                }});


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            imageUri=data.getData();


            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).setAspectRatio(3,2)
                    .start(this);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                imageUri=resultUri;
                selectimage.setImageURI(resultUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: paste your code so other can help to help you to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

According your code and description, I guess:
After you choosed the image and start a activity to crop it,you call "startActivtyForResult" with requestCode = CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE.
When you press the back button to cancel your action;the first Activity still get the callback in function "onActivityResult",the result code is "RESULT_CANCEL".
So you can modify your code like this:

```
if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
 //your code
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the way you said to do but the problem still persist.